# What is the spheroidal temperature of water?

Tags: temperature, water

I understand that when a hot plate reaches a certain temperature water will no longer wet the surface, but will form perfect spheres on the surface of the plate. The temperature at which this happens is the "spheroidal" temperature, but I have been unable to find out any further information about this phenomenon or the exact temperature at which it happens.

Comment: Despite its age, this may be helpful: https://books.google.com/books?id=_2RDAAAAIAAJ&lpg=PA469&ots=xcXFWjbst5&dq=spheroidal%20temp%20water&pg=PA469#v=onepage&q=spheroidal%20temp%20water&f=false

Comment: That is pretty interesting, although somewhat vague. The source says the spheroidal temperature can be anywhere from 288 to 340 degrees (Farenheit presumably).

Comment: Reading a bit further into this, it is a result of the Leidenfrost effect, and the temperature at which it occurs does actually vary depending on a few different things, namely the surface used and the purity of the water. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect

Comment: I was just about to link that. ;)